# Ubuntu 15.10 mini iso preseed not recognized

Tags: preseed, ubuntu-minimal

I downloaded an Ubuntu mini iso from the Ubuntu website and want to do a fully automated install. I created a preseed file([preseed](http://hastebin.com/jukiyelanu.hs))

I created an image with this file in the iso.

When I try to start it with the following contents in the txt.cfg. It asks me all questions and nothing seems to be picked up from the preseed file. This is regarding Ubuntu 15.10

I tried to provide the arguments in different orders and adapting the preseed file. I also tried an Ubuntu server image and it also does not work.

```
default install
label install
    menu label ^Install
    menu default
    kernel linux
    append file=/cdrom/pre.seed priotity=critical locale=en_US console-setup/layoutcode=us vga=788 initrd=initrd.gz quiet ---
```

The versions of the txt.cfg i tried so far : [txt.cfg](http://hastebin.com/haquzuzuru.mel)

Comment: You told it to look in pre.seed, so that is where you need to put your configuration; not txt.cfg.. or tell it to look in txt.cfg instead of pre.seed.

Comment: I found the answer and it is a frustrating thing of Canonical to do with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the result of 30 hours of frustration:

- Ubuntu mini ISO cannot preseed from a file inside an ISO
- Debian netinstall ISO can preseed from a file in the ISO
- Ubuntu and debian Netinstalls cannot retrieve preseed files over SSL

Now i created a public available web server and load the preseed file from there. Why the Ubuntu cannot use a preseed file from in the ISO is a mystery to me, but there must be a valid reason.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if something has changed in later versions, but for Ubuntu 16.04.2 (using mini.iso for amd64), I had to use the following options for preseeding over HTTP:

```
auto=true priority=critial url=http://...
```

Note the addition of `auto=true` (without it, the preseed file is not even considered) and the correct spelling of `priority`. More information about the meaning of these keywords can be found in the manual: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/amd64/apbs02.html

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to extract `initrd.gz`, add the preseed file to root path and pack it again. In boot params `file=/preseed.cfg`.

[Here is an example of how to do that](https://nx3d.org/ubuntu-1804-preseed/)

> First, obtain the compressed `initrd.gz` file and unpack it:
>
> ```
> mkdir preseeded
> cd preseeded && gzip -d < path/to/initrd.gz | cpio -id
> ```
>
> Add the preseed.cfg file and repack the initrd:
>
> ```
> cp mypreseed.cfg preseeded/preseed.cfg
> cd preseeded && find . | cpio -o -H newC | gzip) > path/to/initrd.gz
> ```

I tested this solution on Ubuntu 18.04-LTS and 20.04-LTS, both minimal ISO.

Options with `url=http://xxx/ps.cfg` do not require an extract, of course; works correctly on Debian and Ubuntu.

Params that should be added, from file `auto=true priority=critical file=/preseed.cfg` or from network `auto=true priority=critical url=http://xxx/ps.cfg`

Answer (score 0):

I experimentally found that the menu is stored in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`, not `/isolinux/txt.cfg`.
This is only true if you do EFI Boot, otherwise when creating a isolinux boot ( traditional way )  txt.cfg is used.

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternative to extracting and repackaging `initrd.gz`: Put the preseed file into another initrd (e.g. `preseed.gz`) and chain-load it via

```
initrd=initrd.gz,preseed.gz
```

It has the advantage of not having to temper with the original initrd image.